# Is selling IOS game hacks illegal through some platform?

Tags: hacking

so basically we have a website and we sell monthly subscriptions. The website has a lot of different game hacks and some tutorials for hacking. So, the question is, is this completely illegal? because we are not selling hacks directly, instead we are selling website subscriptions and the users who pay for it can then access the hacks. I live in the United States and am not sure about the laws here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is creating and selling "cheats" or "hacks" for games illegal?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/25825/is-creating-and-selling-cheats-or-hacks-for-games-illegal)

Comment: @BlueDogRanch I think they might be different. The question you've linked to is about selling cheats, but I believe this question is more about hosting a platform where cheats can be accessed.

Comment: @StephanS yeah correct. This question is different than that

Comment: I doubt that a technicality like this "we don't sell the cheats, but we sell a subscription that allows you to access the cheats" would make any difference to the legality. Whether selling these hacks is legal or not would depend on the exact nature of the hack.