# Is breaching ToS of installed software automatically a copyright infringement?

Tags: united-states, copyright

Suppose entity X offers some software (maybe for free, maybe for a price) bundled with some terms of service. Suppose person Y (after paying any relevant price) installs the software following X's instructions. Suppose Y then breaches the terms of service. Has Y then infringed copyright (assuming it is not considered fair use)?

[This answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/25830) presents the following argument:

- Installing the software constituted making a copy of it.
- This copy was only authorized by X on the condition that Y complies with the terms of service.
- This condition was not met, so the copy was not authorized, so it infringed copyright.

This surprised me since I imagined (maybe incorrectly, IANAL) copyright infringement to be a more serious issue than ToS violation. [This article](https://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=e4b1226a-b6b4-4915-8897-a8e474060481) also seems to contradict the above:

> However, if a company violates a license by, for example, failing to purchase additional licenses through the publisher, instead of through an otherwise authorized reseller, then the violation could form the basis of a breach-of-contract claim, but not a copyright claim – none of the exclusive rights would be affected by failure to follow specified payment or transaction terms.

Comment: The second quote seems to be about a dispute over how a license fee is paid. That is not a parallel situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copyright infringement occurs if you make a copy without authorization. I don't believe you can *retroactively* revoke someone's authorization to copy because you don't like what they did later. Therefore, it would seem that your scenario would not be infringement.

It may, however, be a breach of contract, since you promised certain things in exchange for that authorization to copy but did not uphold them.